# too many redirects while accessing wp-admin page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to protect my wp-admin page from bot attacks and found that tutorial about [brute_force_attack](https://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks) where they suggest to allow my specific ip address and deny all. So I created a new .htaccess file in wp-admin folder and write this code according to the website instruction.

`# Block access to wp-admin.
order deny,allow
allow from x.x.x.x // my ip 
deny from all`

But when I'm accessing my website wp-admin/login.php page like example.com/wp-admin/ then I got too many redirects error. 
I'm using shared ip. But I checked several times and confiredby my service provider that my net connection served by only that ip-address. I can access the website but I can't access the admin or login page. I also checked in the main folder .htaccess file and that time I can't even access the website.

Edit: I gave my ip address instead of x.x.x.x .And I'm login into admin page using PC only so ip will not change

Answer (score 0):

Is the `x.x.x.x` IP your office or home ip -- the IP of the laptop machine from which you're trying to connect to your WordPress dashboard? It must be. If you're using the IP of your web site, that's wrong. In many cases, your laptop IP will change with the weather and certainly with your location.

The well-known Jetpack plugin contains a feature called BruteProtect. This uses a crowdsourcing technique to identify and block brute-force attacks on your site and others. Unless there's some strong reason for you not to use that, I suggest you use it. `.htaccess` hacking is a notorious pain in the neck.

In the meantime, if you must use `.htaccess`, try blocking just your login page, like so.

```
 <Files wp-login.php>
   order deny,allow
   allow from x.x.x.x 
   deny from all
 </Files>
```

See if that works.  Then try `<Files *.php>`...

Comment: Actually I want to block all ip-addresses except particular addresses in order to access wp-login.php/admin.php page like this site https://blog.sucuri.net/wp-login.php/ and I tried to do it using .htaccess file. Jetpack blocks when they guess there's an attack from a particular ip-address. But don't block accessing.

Answer (score 0):

```
allow from x.x.x.x `
```

In the above line what exactly is x.x.x.x? 
If it is the global **IP of your WiFi connection** (you can check that in this [Link](http://ip-tracker.org/))
then you should not have any troubles in loggin in from that IP.

But if you have given your **smart phone's IP or smart phone hotspot IP** in case you are using mobile data, the next time you try to access admin page,your IP would have changed hence denying you from accessing it.

Blocking IP is not so convenient as you might have to login from a differnt place, maybe through a different WLAN connection, or through your smart phone.

One of the simple and good ways to **protect your login pages from brute force attacks** is to move wp-login.php / wp-admin. (ex: yoursite.com/wp-admin -> yoursite.com/custompage )

[This Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/) lets you do that easily.

Hope this helps.